# In the figure of Stable Diffusion, when does the switch part change?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, diffusion-models

In the illustration of Stable Diffusion, there is a concatenation part through Cross-Attention. Why is there a switch in the concatenation part?
[image]